# Getting an UnboundLocalError before the start of neural network training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run my code on `Google Colab`, but I am getting an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logs' referenced before assignment
```

The code is executable if I remove the "rows" `steps_per_epoch = train_steps` and `validation_steps = val_steps`. The problem is that an infinite loop is then created in the number of steps, because the neural network does not know how many steps to perform during the epoch.

And this is my code:

```
batch = 16
num_classes = 2
num_epochs = 300
img_width = 200
img_height = 200

train_data_size = [f for f in listdir(train_data_path) if isfile(join(train_data_path, f))]
val_data_size = [f for f in listdir(val_data_path) if isfile(join(val_data_path, f))]

train_steps = len(train_data_size) // batch
val_steps = len(val_data_size) // batch

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_path,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_data_path,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch,
    class_mode='categorical')

model = createModel()

opt = optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0000001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
    callbacks=[checkpoint, csv_logger],
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=val_steps)
```

Full error message:

```
Mounted at /content/drive
2.2.0-rc3 #Tensorflow version
Found 10018 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1336 images belonging to 2 classes.
WARNING:tensorflow:`period` argument is deprecated. Please use `save_freq` to specify the frequency in number of batches seen.
Epoch 1/300
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-dda79f001d12> in <module>()
    102     callbacks=[checkpoint, csv_logger],
    103     validation_data=validation_generator,
--> 104     validation_steps=val_steps)


1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    857               logs = tmp_logs  # No error, now safe to assign to logs.
    858               callbacks.on_train_batch_end(step, logs)
--> 859         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
    860 
    861         # Run validation.

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logs' referenced before assignment
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`batch_size` determines the number of samples in each mini batch. Its maximum is the number of all samples and its minimum is 1, resulting in stochastic gradient descent.

I was able to recreate your error in colab with tensorflow version = 2.2.0rc3. This error occurs when you give the `batch_size`(`batch` in your case) greater than the number of records in validation dataset.

See below the code that I used to recreate the error, I have print all the statistics of the dataset and batch size.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs.zip', origin=_URL, extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'cats_and_dogs_filtered')

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')

batch_size = 1001
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150
print("batch_size:",batch_size)

train_data_size_cat = [f for f in os.listdir(train_cats_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(train_cats_dir, f))]
train_data_size_dog = [f for f in os.listdir(train_dogs_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(train_dogs_dir, f))]

val_data_size_cat = [f for f in os.listdir(validation_cats_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(validation_cats_dir, f))]
val_data_size_dog = [f for f in os.listdir(validation_dogs_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(validation_dogs_dir, f))]

train_steps = (len(train_data_size_cat) + len(train_data_size_dog)) // batch_size
print("Total number of training records:",(len(train_data_size_cat) + len(train_data_size_dog)))
print("steps_per_epoch:",train_steps)

val_steps = (len(val_data_size_cat) + len(val_data_size_dog)) // batch_size
print("Total number of testing records:",(len(val_data_size_cat) + len(val_data_size_dog)))
print("val_steps:",val_steps)

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='binary')

val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])

adam = Adam(lr=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=adam, 
          loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
          train_data_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
          validation_steps=val_steps)
```

Output -

```
2.2.0-rc3
batch_size: 1001
Total number of training records: 2000
steps_per_epoch: 1
Total number of testing records: 1000
val_steps: 0
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/15
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.4582 - accuracy: 0.5165
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-dd9ba773718a> in <module>()
     77           epochs=epochs,
     78           validation_data=val_data_gen,
---> 79           validation_steps=val_steps)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, return_dict)
   1092       callbacks.on_test_end()
   1093 
-> 1094       logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
   1095       if return_dict:
   1096         return logs

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logs' referenced before assignment
```

**Solution -**

Reduce the `batch_size`(`batch` in your case) to smaller size so that it could be more evenly divided during training. For example if I change the `batch_size` to 128 in the above program, it works without any issue.

Fixed Code -

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs.zip', origin=_URL, extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'cats_and_dogs_filtered')

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')

batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150
print("batch_size:",batch_size)

train_data_size_cat = [f for f in os.listdir(train_cats_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(train_cats_dir, f))]
train_data_size_dog = [f for f in os.listdir(train_dogs_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(train_dogs_dir, f))]

val_data_size_cat = [f for f in os.listdir(validation_cats_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(validation_cats_dir, f))]
val_data_size_dog = [f for f in os.listdir(validation_dogs_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(validation_dogs_dir, f))]

train_steps = (len(train_data_size_cat) + len(train_data_size_dog)) // batch_size
print("Total number of training records:",(len(train_data_size_cat) + len(train_data_size_dog)))
print("steps_per_epoch:",train_steps)

val_steps = (len(val_data_size_cat) + len(val_data_size_dog)) // batch_size
print("Total number of testing records:",(len(val_data_size_cat) + len(val_data_size_dog)))
print("val_steps:",val_steps)

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='binary')

val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])

adam = Adam(lr=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=adam, 
          loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
          train_data_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
          validation_steps=val_steps)
```

Output -

```
2.2.0-rc3
batch_size: 128
Total number of training records: 2000
steps_per_epoch: 15
Total number of testing records: 1000
val_steps: 7
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/15
15/15 [==============================] - 29s 2s/step - loss: 7.6643 - accuracy: 0.5031 - val_loss: 7.6436 - val_accuracy: 0.5045
Epoch 2/15
15/15 [==============================] - 29s 2s/step - loss: 7.8217 - accuracy: 0.4947 - val_loss: 7.8158 - val_accuracy: 0.4933
Epoch 3/15
15/15 [==============================] - 29s 2s/step - loss: 7.6819 - accuracy: 0.5011 - val_loss: 7.6780 - val_accuracy: 0.5022
Epoch 4/15
15/15 [==============================] - 29s 2s/step - loss: 7.7494 - accuracy: 0.4995 - val_loss: 7.6436 - val_accuracy: 0.5045
Epoch 5/15
15/15 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 7.5277 - accuracy: 0.5123 - val_loss: 7.7297 - val_accuracy: 0.4989
Epoch 6/15
15/15 [==============================] - 29s 2s/step - loss: 7.9214 - accuracy: 0.4877 - val_loss: 7.7813 - val_accuracy: 0.4955
Epoch 7/15
15/15 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 7.6884 - accuracy: 0.5032 - val_loss: 7.6436 - val_accuracy: 0.5045
Epoch 8/15
15/15 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 7.8426 - accuracy: 0.4904 - val_loss: 7.6953 - val_accuracy: 0.5011
Epoch 9/15
15/15 [==============================] - 29s 2s/step - loss: 7.5759 - accuracy: 0.5075 - val_loss: 7.8330 - val_accuracy: 0.4922
Epoch 10/15
15/15 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 7.6643 - accuracy: 0.5032 - val_loss: 7.6953 - val_accuracy: 0.5011
Epoch 11/15
15/15 [==============================] - 29s 2s/step - loss: 7.7655 - accuracy: 0.4952 - val_loss: 7.7297 - val_accuracy: 0.4989
Epoch 12/15
15/15 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 7.6884 - accuracy: 0.5032 - val_loss: 7.7297 - val_accuracy: 0.4989
Epoch 13/15
15/15 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 7.8362 - accuracy: 0.4915 - val_loss: 7.6953 - val_accuracy: 0.5011
Epoch 14/15
15/15 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 7.4634 - accuracy: 0.5150 - val_loss: 7.6608 - val_accuracy: 0.5033
Epoch 15/15
15/15 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 7.8603 - accuracy: 0.4931 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Alechandro - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.